# I need advice about gradient italic text

Tags: html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

I found a trick to apply a gradient on a text. It work's but when I applied an italic font-style the font is a bit cutted at is extremity

```css
h2 {
  font-family: 'FMono';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 0rem;
  color: #000;
}

h2 > span {
  font-family: 'FMono';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 15rem;
  background: linear-gradient(152.36deg, #FF1053 26.66%, #AF19E4 89.65%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h2>sport your <br> <span>creativity</span> </h2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `padding-left: 10px` to the span...

```css
h2 {
  font-family: 'FMono';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 0rem;
  color: #000;
}

h2 > span {
  font-family: 'FMono';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 15rem;
  background: linear-gradient(152.36deg, #FF1053 26.66%, #AF19E4 89.65%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>sport your <br> <span>creativity</span> </h2>
```